# How to remember login in firebase phone Auth even after app is uninstalled?

Tags: android, authentication, firebase-authentication, login-control

I want to remain user in login state even after the app is uninstalled. I use phone Auth for Firebase. From Stack overflow I found and tasted the following code for checking if user exist or not :

```
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(PhoneAuthActivity.this, MainActivityDriverLogin.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(PhoneAuthActivity.this, "Please Write Your Phone Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
};
```

and I set onStart :

```
mAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
```

but, no luck,  When I install app again, I have to use phone Number again.

I also tried in Manifests :

```
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="true"
```

But, though the login has lost.

Is there any way for one time login in app, and remain login even the app unistalled or even clear cache from system ?

Comment: You can use the device IMEI and save it in your server(Firebase DB), then when your preferences are empty just check if the server got a device with the same IMEI.

Comment: the problem is that, For entering DB for First Time, need Auth, because in db rules I set "auth!=null" .

Comment: So you can check if the IMEI exist on your server if not request to auth

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for smart lock feature in android.[Google smartlock](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6197437?hl=en&visit_id=636914310491577930-66520261&rd=1).
You need to enable the feature on your authenitication. I assume you are using Firbase Authenitaction Ui using this method **.setIsSmartLockEnabled(true)**

```
AuthUI.getInstance()
                                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                    .setIsSmartLockEnabled(true)
                                    .setProviders(Arrays.asList(
                                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build()))
                                    .build(), RC_SIGN_IN
                            );
```